# Nancy WithMediaRangeResponse for Accept types that vary by parameter only

Tags: c#, nancy

I have a nancy endpoint that should support two content-types:

```
application/vnd.mycompany.something+json;version=1
application/vnd.mycompany.something+json;version=2
```

I want to return a different response based upon the version parameter of the Accept header.

I am trying to use this code, which seems rational, but it is always matching V1.  Is there anything I can do to make the matching more specific?

```
return this.Negotiate
    .WithMediaRangeResponse(new MediaRange("application/vnd.mycompany.something+json;version=1"), () => {
            return someV2Response;
        })
    .WithMediaRangeResponse(new MediaRange("application/vnd.mycompany.something+json;version=2"), () => {
            return someV2Response;
        })
    .WithMediaRangeResponse( new MediaRange("*/*"), () => new Response { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable });
```